# sp_execute SQL giving different results to raw query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net

I have found a few similar questions to this but all the solutions seem to relate to passing date parameters to sp_executesql which is not what I am doing...

I have a .NET application which connects to a SQL database using the SqlConnection and SqlCommand classes. When I run the application and monitor the database queries using SQL Server Profiler, I can see that the .NET app is generating the following code:

```
exec sp_executesql N'IF object_id(''tempdb..#ParmsInProc'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ParmsInProc 
                     SELECT o.name AS ProcName, o.object_id, p.name AS ParamName, p.system_type_id, p.user_type_id
                     INTO   #ParmsInProc
                     FROM   sys.objects o
                            JOIN sys.parameters p
                                ON o.object_id = p.object_id
                            JOIN sys.types t
                                ON t.system_type_id = p.system_type_id AND t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
                    WHERE   type_desc = ''SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'' AND o.name = ''@sp''

                    SELECT  * 
                    FROM    #ParmsInProc p        
                            LEFT JOIN ( 
                                            SELECT  * 
                                            FROM    #ParmsInProc 
                                            WHERE   system_type_id = 56 AND user_type_id = 56 
                                        ) ints 
                                ON p.system_type_id = ints.system_type_id AND p.user_type_id = ints.user_type_id',N'@sp nvarchar(14)',@sp=N'sp_myProcedure'
```

If I run that code in SSMS, I get no results. However, if I copy out the query and replace the parameter placeholder with the actual value, I get

```
IF  object_id('tempdb..#ParmsInProc') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ParmsInProc 
SELECT  o.name AS ProcName, o.object_id, p.name AS ParamName, p.system_type_id, p.user_type_id
INTO    #ParmsInProc
FROM    sys.objects o
        JOIN sys.parameters p
            ON o.object_id = p.object_id
        JOIN sys.types t
            ON t.system_type_id = p.system_type_id AND t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
WHERE   type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' AND o.name = 'sp_myProcedure'

SELECT  * 
FROM    #ParmsInProc p        
        LEFT JOIN ( 
                        SELECT  * 
                        FROM    #ParmsInProc 
                        WHERE   system_type_id = 56 AND user_type_id = 56 
                    ) ints 
            ON p.system_type_id = ints.system_type_id AND p.user_type_id = ints.user_type_id
```

and if I run that, I get one result (which is the outcome I expect)

What could be causing this?

Comment: `Declare @sp` and `Set @sp` Initial stage and Try.

Comment: I don't think that it is the issue, but parameters are NVARCHARS while your string is VARCHAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to "debug" your initial query, you will see that `@sp` is being passed as a procedure name, instead of the actual value for your parameter.

You can see this by writing the following:

```
declare @spname nvarchar(100) = 'my_storedproc';
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '   IF object_id(''tempdb..#ParmsInProc'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ParmsInProc 
                                 SELECT o.name AS ProcName, o.object_id, p.name AS ParamName, p.system_type_id, p.user_type_id
                                 INTO   #ParmsInProc
                                 FROM   sys.objects o
                                        JOIN sys.parameters p
                                            ON o.object_id = p.object_id
                                        JOIN sys.types t
                                            ON t.system_type_id = p.system_type_id AND t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
                                WHERE   type_desc = ''SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'' AND o.name = ''@sp'';

                                SELECT  * 
                                FROM    #ParmsInProc p        
                                        LEFT JOIN ( 
                                                        SELECT  * 
                                                        FROM    #ParmsInProc 
                                                        WHERE   system_type_id = 56 AND user_type_id = 56 
                                                    ) ints 
                                            ON p.system_type_id = ints.system_type_id AND p.user_type_id = ints.user_type_id;'
print @sql
```

The following is being generated:

[image]

What you need to do is to just pass it as a parameter, no need for quotes. 
I modified a little your query just to be able to print it, by storing the sql query into a variable but you can of course execute it as you had it, inline:

```
declare @spname nvarchar(100) = 'my_storedproc';
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '   IF object_id(''tempdb..#ParmsInProc'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ParmsInProc 
                                 SELECT o.name AS ProcName, o.object_id, p.name AS ParamName, p.system_type_id, p.user_type_id
                                 INTO   #ParmsInProc
                                 FROM   sys.objects o
                                        JOIN sys.parameters p
                                            ON o.object_id = p.object_id
                                        JOIN sys.types t
                                            ON t.system_type_id = p.system_type_id AND t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
                                WHERE   type_desc = ''SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'' AND o.name = @sp;

                                SELECT  * 
                                FROM    #ParmsInProc p        
                                        LEFT JOIN ( 
                                                        SELECT  * 
                                                        FROM    #ParmsInProc 
                                                        WHERE   system_type_id = 56 AND user_type_id = 56 
                                                    ) ints 
                                            ON p.system_type_id = ints.system_type_id AND p.user_type_id = ints.user_type_id;'
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@sp nvarchar(100)', @sp = @spname
```

This will execute successfully and you get to see the printed sql query under the Messages tab :)